# How to change values in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I change value of price (in wordpress) which is set for numeric values? I want to change the value to display text or numeric from url (scraping api)

right now my class_core.php file shows this:

```
Price Display
   ========================================================================== */
function PRICE($val){
// RETURN IF NOT NUMERIC
if(!is_numeric($val) && defined('WLT_JOBS') ){ return $val; } 


if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency'])){  
    $seperator = "."; $sep = ","; $digs = 2; 
    if(is_numeric($val)){       
    $val = number_format($val,$digs, $seperator, $sep); 
    }
    $val = hook_price_filter($val);

    // RETURN IF EMPTY
    if($val == ""){ return $val; }

    // LEFT/RIGHT POSITION
    if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency']['position']) && $GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency']['position'] == "right"){ 
        if(substr($val,-3) == ".00"){ $val = substr($val,0,-3); }
        $val = $val.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency']['symbol'];
    }else{
        $val = $GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency']['symbol'].$val;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm learning from you.  I see that number_format() is a php function, but I don't understand hook_price_filter()  I can't find that in core WordPress. What plugin are you using?

Comment: responsive price comparison theme

Comment: Hmm.. Its not totally clear on what you are trying to do.  I assumed you already have performed the web site scraping, and have something in $val.  It almost sounds like you are new to this stuff, not quite clear on what scraping is, and you want to obtain content from another web site, then start from the beginning?  Help us understand what you are trying to do, and whay you've already accomplished..

Comment: Yes I am new to this. I have setup crawler which scrapes the price from various pages . This crawler gives me an api (url) which i want to post instead of numeric values. Now how do I program it to get the data from url and if the data from url is not available then to use another variable which would contain a fallback price. I want to use this api because the crawler runs every 15 minutes and could help me in getting live data .

Comment: It is for my ecommerce website , are there any pointers that I could use?

Comment: Why don't I delete my first answer (which converts a string like $100 to a number 100) and try responding again..

Comment: ?sorry I dont understand what you said

Answer (score 0):

php is a scripting language. you dont have to declare what kind of variable you will be using. You just declare the name and the type of the variable change automatically depending on what data are you storing.

Comment: I have setup crawler which scrapes the price from various pages . This crawler gives me an api (url) which i want to post instead of numeric values. Now how do I program it to get the data from url and if the data from url is not available then to use another variable which would contain a fallback price. I want to use this api because the crawler runs every 15 minutes and could help me in getting live data   -------------                                           Referring to my above comment can you please tell me how I should go ahead with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a url that contains some information, like (www.xyz.com/dddddd/ddddd) you can use CURL to obtain a result...

(ref: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)

```
function curl_download($Url){
  // is cURL installed yet?
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
      die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
  }
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}
```

and then in your code...

```
 $url_for_value = "www.xyz.com/dddddd/ddddd";   
 // remember to add http colon and two slashes in front of url...
 // stackoverflow tools won't let me do that here...
 $val = curl_download($url_for_value);

 function PRICE($val){

 if(!is_numeric($val) && defined('WLT_JOBS') ){ 
    // if not numeric,  e.g. $100 , strip off non-numeric characters.
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $val, $match);
    // Do we have a valid number now?
    if (!is_numeric($match[0]){
        // perform other tests on return info from the CURL function?
        return $val;
    }   
    $val = $match[0];
 } 

if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['currency'])){  ....
```

Note: Its certainly admirable to have a need for a specific function, and then use that need to motivate you to learn new skills. This project assumes a certain experience in HTML, PHP and WordPress. If you don't feel comfortable in that stuff yet, that's okay, we all started knowing nothing.

Here's a possible learning roadmap:

--HTML  Learn the organization of a website, elements, and how to create forms, buttons, etc...
--PHP   This is a scripting language, runs on a server.
--CSS   You will need this for WordPress. (Why? Because we insist on you using a child theme, and that will require to understand how CSS works. )

--JavaScript, although not absolutely required, lots of existing tools use this.

There are a lot of free tutorials on this stuff.  I'd probably start at http://html.net/ or somewhere like that.  Do all the tutorials.

After that you get to jump into WordPress.  Start small, modify a few sites, then grow to writing your own plugins.  At that point, I think you should be able to easily create the functionality you are looking for.

If not, it could well be quicker to hire the job out.  eLance is your friend.

Comment: url is added later from user end so for 1st line what do I add ?

Comment: whoa.. are you asking me how to get a response from the user on a web page, and then use it in a wordpress / php website?  Like basic HTML form stuff?

Comment: No,  Response from user on web page stuff is in place .  (www.xyz.com/dddddd/ddddd) was just an example , program has to be for any url given in input. Does the above support same ( I am a beginner) ?

Comment: Yes, you can curl to any website.  Try it yourself from a your command line terminal on your computer. type ` curl www.google.com` Please remember to add the http stuff before the url.. stackoverflow blocks that from my entries...

Comment: Should I write the first code you gave in functions.php?

Comment: Truthfully, I think this may be beyond your current level of expertise.  Anything can (and will) go wrong.  If you need this fast, hire it done.  If not fast, then start working on tutorials.  Good luck with it.  Note: do accept my answer or reject it (green check mark on left hand margin...) thanks.

Comment: Your answer was very useful for me .. You are right I should start some tutorials. Thank you very much !!

Comment: Can you explain a little more of that code. See I make a living out of the site . Please help

Comment: "I make a living out of the site"  Me too. How much help do I need to offer? (http://vimeo.com/22053820) No offense intended.

Comment: This code is giving me 500 internal error. I can pay you if you integrate and give me